# Extracting a multiple level XML using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm trying to extract data from an XML file.

The format of the XML is as follows:

```
<notifications>
<notification name="ccmSmtp" oid="1.3.6.1" status="current">
  <objects>
    <object module="callhome" name="ccmSmtp"/>
  </objects>
  <description>
     This is a description
  </description>
</notification>
<notification name="ccmAlertGroup" oid="1.3.6.1" status="current">
  <objects>
    <object module="callhome" name="callHome"/>
  </objects>
  <description>
       This is a description
  </description>
</notification>
<notification name="ccmAlert" oid="1.3.6.1" status="current">
  <objects>
    <object module="callhome" name="callHome"/>
  </objects>
  <description>
    This is a description
  </description>
</notification>
<notification name="ccmSmtp" oid="1.3.6.1" status="current">
  <objects>
  </objects>
  <description>
      This is a description
  </description>
</notification>
</notifications>
```

I have written the following code to extract the notifications node from example.xml file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

$xml = new XML::Simple;

$data = $xml->XMLin("example.xml",KeyAttr => {
  notifications => notification => 'name'
});

$notification = $data->{notifications};

print Dumper($notification);
```

When I run the above Perl file I get the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'notification' => [
      {
        'objects' => {
          'object' => {
            'name' => 'ccmSmtp',
            'module' => 'callhome'
          }
        },
        'status' => 'current',
        'oid' => '1.3.6.',
        'name' => 'ccmSmtp',
        'description' => ' This is a mib '
      },
      {
        'objects' => {
          'object' => {
            'name' => 'callHome',
            'module' => 'module'
          }
        },
        'status' => 'current',
        'oid' => '1.3.6.1.4',
        'name' => 'ccmAlert',
        'description' => 'This is a description'
      },
      {
        'objects' => {
          'object' => {
            'name' => 'callHome',
            'module' => 'homemib'
          }
        },
        'status' => 'current',
        'oid' => '1.3.6.1.4',
        'name' => 'ccmAlertf',
        'description' => 'This is a description'
      },
      {
        'objects' => {},
        'status' => 'current',
        'oid' => '1.3.6.1',
        'name' => 'ccmSmtp',
        'description' => ' This is an example'
      }
    ]
};
```

My question is, how can I extract the contents of notification node and store the values in separate variables/array ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally for extracting items from XML I would start with XPath. There is an XPath package for Perl, probably even in the XML package you're already using.

Answer (score 1):

`$notification` is just a ref to a hash with one key 'notification' that has an array of hashes.

You could loop through it by doing

```
for my $n ( @{$notification->{notification}} ) {
    # ie. to get status out, this is same for description,oid,name
    my $status = $n->{status};

    # To get the nested 'objects' data object module value (phew)
    my $object_module = $n->{status}{object}{module};

}
```

Comment: Running through the code code suggested gives the following output " Not an ARRAY reference "

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear what it is you want. The code you posted did not produce that output as it will not compile, but if you wrote instead

```
my $data = $xml->XMLin("x.xml", KeyAttr => ['notification']);
print Dumper $data;
```

then you would get exactly that. Now $data->{notification} is a reference to an array of four hashes (corresponding to the four  elements) which can be accessed as

```
my $note0 = $data->{notification}[0];
```

etc. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi Borodin, I tried as you said, but by giving a print $note0 does not give me any output. :-(

Comment: Are you sure you have 'notification' in every case instead of 'notifications'? You should also 'use strict' and 'use warnings' at the top of everything you write to obtain better information about any bugs that arise.

Answer (score 0):

I would looped like below :

```
foreach $NOTIFICATION( @{$data->{'notification}}) 
{   
foreach $OBJECT (@{$NOTIFICATION->{'OBJECT'}}) 
{
$name=$NOTIFICATION->{'name'};                                 $module=$OBJECT->{'module'}; 

Print $name , $module 
}
}
```

Comment: You should at least provide some indentation and explain your solution a little bit...